# p-value histogram of two-sample poisson tests on simulated data

Tags: p-value, poisson-distribution, histogram, two-sample

I have two vectors (a and b), which are each a sample of n = 10000 from the poisson distribution with lambda = 10.

```
x <- data.frame("a" = rpois(10000,1000), "b" = rpois(10000,1000))
```

I conduct 10000 two-sample poisson tests between each element of a and the corresponding element of b, where the null hypothesis is that the two numbers are from the same poisson distribution (the rate ratio is 1).

```
x$p.value <- NA
for (i in 1:nrow(x)) {
  temp <- poisson.test(c(x[i, "a"], x[i, "b"]), T = c(1,1), alternative = "two.sided")
  x$p.value[i] <- temp$p.value }
```

As the null hypothesis is obviously true for this simulated data, I would expect the 10000 resulting p-values to be evenly distributed between 0 and 1. However, this is not the case. Instead the histogram shows a significant rightward skew towards 1.

```
hist(x$p.value, breaks = seq(0,1, by = 0.01))
```

[image]

Why is this the case?

Comment: You are not reading the histogram correctly.  By definition, histograms represent probability by means of *area,* not height.  Look closely at the right hand side and notice that the high bars are balanced by neighboring low bars, producing a very uniform density across the board.  This phenomenon (of bar heights bouncing around) is *aliasing* in the binning process, as discussed at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/401692/what-is-this-phenomenon-called.  Use a uniform probability plot instead.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and relevant links, this has solved the problem for me!