# Who was the first person to prove the straight line cross probability for a Brownian motion?

Tags: probability, references, history, brownian-motion

In the paper "Heuristic approach to the Kolmogorov-Smirnov theorems" by J.L. Doob (1949) it's mencioned this well-known theorem:
If $\zeta=\{\zeta_{t}|t\geq 0\}$ is a Brownian motion then
$$P(\sup_{t\in\mathbb{R}}\{\zeta_{t}\}\geq at+b)=e^{-2ab}$$

but it's not referenced so I don't know who proved it first

Answer (score 5):

A similar problem is [The magic money tree problem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/401480/) which is a problem of a random walk with drift.

That problem is a discrete random walk but it has a comparable problem with continuous Brownian motion.

An early occurance of an equation that solves this problem is by Smoluchowski

> Smoluchowski, Marian V. "Über Brownsche Molekularbewegung unter Einwirkung äußerer Kräfte und deren Zusammenhang mit der verallgemeinerten Diffusionsgleichung." *Annalen der Physik* 353.24 (1916): 1103-1112. (online available via: https://www.physik.uni-augsburg.de/theo1/hanggi/History/BM-History.html)
>
> Equation 8:
>
> $$ W(x_0,x,t) = \frac{e^{-\frac{c(x-x_0)}{2D} - \frac{c^2 t}{4D}}}{2 \sqrt{\pi D t}} \left[ e^{-\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{4Dt}} - e^{-\frac{(x+x_0)^2}{4Dt}} \right]$$

You can rewrite this as the difference of two normal distribution density functions

$$ W(x_0,x,t) = \frac{  e^{-\frac{(x-x_0+ct)^2}{4Dt}} - \left(e^{{c x_0/D}}\right) e^{-\frac{(x+x_0+ct)^2}{4Dt}} }{ \sqrt{4\pi D t}}$$

and the integral $\int_0^\infty W(x_0,x,t) dx$ is in the limit $t \to \infty$ equal to $1-e^{c x_0/D}$

(The case where $c$, the 'fallgeschwindigkeit', is negative relates to a drift away from $x=0$, and relates to a positive $a$ in the line $at +b$ from the question)

I am not sure whether Smoluchowski ever computed that integral, but he did provide a solution to a problem which is a major part of this derivation.